# How to manually create controller as a service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I would like to create controllers as services, and additionally create them manually.

In order to do so, I added some code in "Startup" class, my "ConfigureServices" method starts with:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddSignalR();
  services.AddControllers()
    .AddControllersAsServices()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson();
  ...
```

`AddControllersAsServices` supposedly switches to controllers as services with transient lifetime. Knowing this I added:

```
...
services.AddTransient<MyController>(sp =>
{
  return new MyController(
    sp.GetService<ILogger>(),
    sp.GetService<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.IAuthorizationService>(),
    ...
});
```

but when I try to run it I get error on IHostBuilder `Build` method call (in "Program.cs"):

> 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MyController Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: MyController': A suitable constructor for type 'MyController' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.)'

"AddTransient" call is executed, but the body of it -- no, and judging by the error message it looks like the system relied on classic DI instead of the entry provided directly by me.

So how to force the usage of the entry I defined?

Comment: does your controller only have non-default(paramsless) constructor?

Comment: @LeiYang, yes/no. I have one **internal** constructor, non default (i.e. **with** parameters). Parameterless would be default. Since I would be going through manual creation and not automatic-DI, internal should be fine.

Comment: Isn't the default lifetime of a Controller transient?

Comment: @AchoVasilev, from what I've read it is is, and that is why I called `AddTransient` (see: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/426254/why-controller-lifetime-is-transient-by-default-in-asp-net-core) so when it will be picked up later, both lifetime and type will give a match. But something went wrong here and I don't see what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I found it: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/27959 Just before calling `Build` on "IHostBuilder" one has to call:

```
 .UseDefaultServiceProvider((context, options) =>
    {
        options.ValidateOnBuild = false;
    })
```